# Sorting Array of Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, pointers

Hoping I can get a little advice on a sorting method I made.

The purpose of this code is to create a int pointer array and sort the pointers in that array by the contents of regular int array.  Then assign values for a different variable based on the location of the original int array.

The strangeness I am experiencing with this code is that the test code which shouldn't effect anything as far as I know... IS actually effecting the contents of my pointers.
Perhaps the values aren't changing but the way I'm writing the test code is causing errors.

```
 //create array
 int c[8] = {3,1,5,7,8,2,6,4};
 //create pointer array
 int *newptr[8];
 for(int k = 0; k<8; k++)
 {
     newptr[k] = &c[k];
 }
//sort pointer array
for(int j = 0; j<8; j++)
{
    for(; j > -1 && *newptr[j] < *newptr[j+1]; j--)
    {
        int *temp = newptr[j+1];
        newptr[j+1] = newptr[j];
        newptr[j] = temp;
    }
}
//set lookuplocation
int lookuplocation;
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
{
    cout << *newptr[i];

    if(newptr[i] == &c[0])
    {
        cout << *newptr[i] << endl;

        //If I use endl or \n to test the pointers values I end up with only
        //a part of the correct data. 

        cout << "\nSuccess!\n";
        lookuplocation = 0;
    }
}
//Also for my last test sometimes the first element gets messed up as well
//test arrays
for(int k = 0; k<8; k++)
{
    cout << "Element " << k << ": " << *newptr[k] << endl;
    cout << "Element " << k << ": " << newptr[k] << endl;
}
```

Comment: your sorting is messed up

Comment: Nested loops with the same counter j ? How can it work at all?

Comment: no its not.  It works just fine, I added only a little more to my current code before I got small bugs, and they still can be bypassed. I was just curious to why I was getting them in the first place.

Comment: how are the pointers uninitialized?

Comment: You're initializing pointers with the addresses of a stack variable here. That is going to explode if you return any of those pointers, and it's going to explode spectacularly. Don't do that.

Comment: @user2651901, They're not, it's bedtime. I can at least leave some advice and say to use `std::swap`, which shouldn't violate any reasonable restrictions that led to not using `std::sort`.

Comment: also the only thing so far that messes up the code is using endl and \n for my test code, otherwise i get the correct values being display

Comment: i'm getting Segmentation fault with this code for no reason... can't even debug it, sry....

Comment: Do you need to write the code to sort the array of pointers, or do you need to sort an array of pointers? Please specify which. If you don't need to write your own code, the solution is trivial.

Comment: @chris hayes: why is using a pointer to the address of a array elements cause it to explode?

Comment: @juan I'm writing the code for a class so I have to write my own, so far I am sorting the array of pointers I made for the original array of ints.  After that I am using the array of pointers to set index locations that I can use for my other program that has other arrays of data.

Comment: Why don't you use some sort of STL container?

Comment: @Cengiz Kandemir: I wasn't really taught to use them in class.

Comment: i got it to work, but i had to change it. otherwise the segmentation fault killed the program

Comment: @No Idea For Name: try getting rid of or adding the endl for the for loop containing "look up location".  It changes the outcome quite strangely.

Comment: @no idea for name: also if u get rid of that for loop altogether, the code works just fine.

Comment: I notice that anything I put between
    if(newptr[i] == &c[0])
    {
    }
it fails...

Comment: *"I wasn't really taught to use them (STL containers) in class."* - Of course you weren't, because eveybody knows *C++* is best taught by teaching *"C with `cout`"* first. ;)

Comment: Your code has a bug. In the sorting loop, when `j==7` the expression `newptr[j+1]` accesses an element past the end of the array.

Comment: @blastfurnance: didnt notice that, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured someone might actually need to sort an array of pointers in a sane way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 8> arr { 3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 7, 6, 8 };
    std::array<int*, 8> p_arr;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        p_arr[i] = &arr[i];
    }

    std::sort(p_arr.begin(), p_arr.end(), [](int* a, int* b) { return *a < *b; });

    for (auto i : p_arr) 
        std::cout << *i;
}
```

The ugly middle loop is totally replace'able by range for over `zip`pped range, but I don't have my own implementation with reference semantics right now, and I am too lazy to check the Boost one.<sup>1</sup>

[Here's a live sample on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e5adccf91ef2cb2c113d80bd12ba5047-4633dfbb9751bd61e16305d67167e3f8).

Also, because I think we should repeat this over and over until newbies understand it:

- Don't reinvent the sorting wheel (unless it's a toy implementation)
- Try to avoid using pointers in C++ if reasonably possible.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is actually important in order to make sure both ranges (in this case two arrays) have the same length. Different zipping conventions either require the ranges to be of the same length (crashing or throwing otherwise) or fill in the empty data should one of the ranges be too short. While seemingly obvious in such a simple program, be careful in real-world code.

Comment: @user2651901 you should learn Standard Library **before** pointers.

Answer (score 3):

If your array `c[n]` has for range [1 .. *n*], you can use the following algorithm which work in O(*n*) time complexity:

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    while(*newptr[*newptr[j] - 1] != *newptr[j])
        std::swap(newptr[*newptr[j] - 1], newptr[j]);
```

The idea behind it is to assign the value 1 to the pointer `newptr[0]`, 2 to the pointer `newptr[1]`, ..., and *n* to the pointer `newptr[n-1]`. There is no algorithm that is more efficient (especially in C++11, since `std::swap` will use `std::move`).

So for `int c[8] = {3,1,5,7,8,2,6,4}`, you get (disregarding the reference to value table):

> 1233
>
> Success!
> 45678

---

**Update:** If you want the reverse order:

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    while(*newptr[n - *newptr[j]] != *newptr[j])
        std::swap(newptr[n - *newptr[j]], newptr[j]);
```

For `int c[8] = {3,1,5,7,8,2,6,4}`, you get:

> 8765433
>
> Success!
> 21

Comment: While this does work, it sorts the opposite way which I'm sure can be easily fixed.  But my main problem that I'm dealing with is understanding whether or not I can do a comparison of the address of my original int array and the pointers.  I'm pretty sure now that is what was messing up my code.

Comment: @user2651901: You mean you want the script to sort from 8 to 1 instead of 8 to 1?

Comment: yeah 8 to 1 not 1 to 8.

Comment: While this has been posted quite a while ago, I think it's necessary to point out that this is not exactly O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Popular approach is to implement generic `sort` function that sorts elements with given comparator, so you can abstract over array elements. There are some ways:

```
template<typename ElementType, typename CompType>
void sort(ElementType array[], size_t size, CompType cmp);
template<typename ElementType, typename CompType>
void sort(std::vector<ElementType> & array, CompType cmp);
template<typename IteratorType, typename CompType>
void sort(IteratorType first, IteratorType last, CompType cmp);
```

Last way is preferable because you can abstract over container type too.

Answer (score 0):

Change this first:

`for(; j > -1 && *newptr[j] < *newptr[j+1]; j--)`

into

`for(int i=j; i > -1 && *newptr[i] < *newptr[i+1]; i--)`

It seems alot more efficient..

Comment: but very confusing. simplicity is more important to me at this point.

Comment: it's not, reusing the same j is confusing, it actually might lower the j in your outer loop which is probably not the purpose?

Comment: Hmm. Now that I think about it, it does reduce the amount of processing of numbers.  It isn't necessary but it is a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: @irW "alot" more efficient? [link](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.hu/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Comment: yes you are right, it won't have a big impact, still it is silly to decrease the j in the outer loop since there is no reason for that. (when I wrote 'alot' I was incorreclty assuming j -> 0 every time)

Comment: @irW Ah, I was not referring to the amount of efficiency gained by any means. Click that link, really.

Comment: Hehe, funny link, English is not my mother language so I tend to make mistakes, your creature might help me in remembering this error ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
void sortList(int* list, const size_t &len)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = i+1; j < len; ++j)
        {
            if (list[i] > list[j])
            {
                std::swap(list[i], list[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```