# C++ - sort array by Date

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am learning C++. I have created two structs (Date and Phone):

```
struct Date {
    unsigned int day, month, year;
};

struct Phone {
    std::string name;
    Date purchase_date;
};
```

Then I insert some data with std::cin for multiple phones. My main function:

```
int main()
{
    Phone *phone[3];
    phone[0] = new Phone;
    phone[1] = new Phone;
    phone[2] = new Phone;
    
    insertDataForPhone(*phone, 3);

    for(unsigned short itr = 0; itr < 3; itr++)
    {
        delete phone[itr];
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

My question there is: How can I sort array phone by Date that I have created (Ascending)?

Comment: For sorting you should use STL's sort functions, unless you want to reinvent a wheel for learning purposes, but there are lots of issues with this your current code, which I doubt that would even compile...

Comment: Can I do it somehow with moving pointers?

Comment: The various library sorting functions all accept a custom function that can be made to take pointers and then perform the compare on a member of the pointed-top object. Is [Sorting Array of Pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052204/sorting-array-of-pointers-in-c) enough to get you started?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, I believe you'll find it easier to understand than operator overloading since you're learning C++. If you have further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: @LukeG, take a look at this link for example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-c-stl/

Comment: Note that the Geeks for Geeks example will not compile on most compilers, does not cover how to sort pointed-at objects, and uses  C++ idioms that are about 10 years out of date.  Not a good example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::sort` with a custom comparator. The comparator is used to tell if the first argument is "less" than the second argument:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // std::sort
#include <string>     // std::string, std::begin, std::end

struct Date {
  unsigned int day, month, year;
};

// Compare dates
bool operator<(Date const& lhs, Date const& rhs) noexcept {
  if (lhs.year < rhs.year) return true;
  if (lhs.year > rhs.year) return false;

  if (lhs.month < rhs.month) return true;
  if (lhs.month > rhs.month) return false;

  return lhs.day < rhs.day;
}

struct Phone {
  std::string name;
  Date purchase_date;
};

// Comparator for sorting
bool purchased_earlier(Phone const* p1, Phone const* p2) noexcept {
  return p1->purchase_date < p2->purchase_date;
}

int main() {
  Phone* phone[3];
  // ...
  std::sort(std::begin(phone), std::end(phone), purchased_earlier);
}
```

In the case of the `Date` class, it makes sense to just compare them. So, I overloaded `operator<`. In the case `Phone`, it doesn't make much sense to compare phones and isn't super obvious that we're doing it based on purchase date, so I created a named function which I pass to `std::sort`.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can map those phones by their purchase dates and it's **automatically sorted** thanks to `std::map`. If you're learning C++, this is much simpler and you'll learn to use `tm` structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <map>
struct Phone{
    std::string name;
    tm purchase_date;
};
std::map<time_t,Phone*> Phones;
int main()
{
    Phone* phone1=new Phone{"phone1",{0,0,0,9,0,121}}; //01.09.21
    Phone* phone2=new Phone{"phone2",{0,0,0,30,11,120}}; //12.30.20
    Phones[mktime(&phone1->purchase_date)]=phone1;
    Phones[mktime(&phone2->purchase_date)]=phone2;
    for(auto it=Phones.begin(); it!=Phones.end(); it++)
        std::cout<<it->second->name<<std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
phone2
phone1
```

Because *phone2* was purchased earlier.